# mysql creation of temp table very slow

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql in 2 different systems. I have 1 system with ubuntu and another one with debian.

I have to create a temp table at some point in order to present the data and what is really strange is that on the ubuntu system, it takes 400 ms (response from browser) and on the debian it takes more than 10 seconds !!!

I have checked 2 values in the mysql config and I have:
show global variables like 'tmp_table_size'; which is the same on both servers: 16777216

But the difference is:
show global status like 'created_tmp_disk_tables'; which gives 11 on the fast server and 102 on the slow server.

I don't really know where else to look and how to optimise it so that I have the same on both servers.

Of course my production server is on the debian.

The fast server is running: mysql version 5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
The slow server is running: mysql version 5.5.55-0+deb8u1

On the fast server, I have:

```
show global variables like 'default_tmp_storage_engine';
+----------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name              | Value  |
+----------------------------+--------+
| default_tmp_storage_engine | InnoDB |
+----------------------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

On the slow server, I have:

```
show global variables like 'default_tmp_storage_engine';
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Do you create a temporary table with data or only with the empty structure?

Comment: with data like 1000 rows which is not enormous

Comment: Probably, selecting these 1000 rows is the real problem? Can you check this?

Comment: Can you check the config variable `default_tmp_storage_engine` on both servers?

Comment: The fast server is responding InnoDB and the other one responds Empty

Comment: MySQL 5.5. and 5.7. differ by two major versions and do a lot of thing very differently. Thus, the reason your query performs differently can have several reasons. You will have to optimize your 5.5. query independently from 5.7. It's hard to assist you there without more (we currently have none) information (required: query (that fills the temp table), explain output, table descriptions, maybe the code that uses the temp table). One thing you might want to try first is to use `create temporary table... engine=memory` when you create your temp table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggestion to consider for your my.cnf-ini

```
max_heap_table_size=16M  # and should always be same as tmp_table_size
```

SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%tmp_table_size' may be used on each version to see what you have at this time.

Global variable default_tmp_storage_engine was added between 5.5 and 5.7.

For additional assistance please find contact information in my profile.

Comment: @richard How long is it taking now on Debian?  For additional assistance please find contact in formation in my profile, Network profile.

Comment: I have upgraded the mysql to the same version and used engine=memory and I have now everything at the same speed. Thank you.

Comment: Please tell me how?

Comment: @Richard If you would like additional improvements in performance, please look at Jun 20 comment from me at 15:05.  Thanks.